# Make a http multipart request that has post data and a file upload

Tags: php, file-upload, http-post, multipartform-data

I'm trying to send a post request to a php file that has post data and a file upload, here is the contents of what I am sending, the code for setting the headers, the php file I have, and what I am getting back from the php file: (the [image file content] is a placeholder for the binary data of the image file I am sending)

My problem is that neither $_POST & $_FILES are showing empty arrays.  I am trying to figure out how to fix that.

//data I am sending to the server:

```
--boundary
content-disposition: post; name='param1'

value1
--boundary
content-disposition: post; name='field2'

value2
--boundary
content-disposition: post; name='field3'

value3
--boundary
content-disposition: form-data; name='file'; filename='app/native/assets/sampleFile.jpg'
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

[image file content]
--boundary--

-----------------------------------------------------
```

for my headers, I have:

```
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "mulipart/form-data, boundary=boundary");
//data holds the string above
request.setRawHeader("Content-Length", QString::number(data.length()).toAscii());
```

---

php file:

```
<?php
  echo "\npost:\n\n";
  print_r($_POST);

  echo "\nfiles:\n\n";
  print_r($_FILES);
?>
```

---

result from php file:

```
post:

Array
(
)

files:

Array
(
)
```

---

Comment: I had an issue with this myself a couple weeks ago. Have you tried sending a file only or post data only to see if they show up? We ended up finding that php.ini needed to be set to accept larger files.

Comment: your `multipart/form-data` is **mulipart**. try `var_dump`ing the `$_REQUEST` variable

Comment: What environment are you sending the request from?

Answer (score 3):

Try something like

```
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="param1"

value1
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field2"

value2
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field3"

value3
--boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="app/native/assets/sampleFile.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

[image file content]
--boundary--
```

```
request.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=boundary");
```

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed I was putting "post" where I should have been using "form-data", I changed them to "form-data", but I am still getting blank results from my php file.

Comment: @user1296259 Did you add the terminating boundary and fix the content-type header from `mulipart/form-data,` to `multipart/form-data;`? Also are you sure you're setting the content length to the correct value?